# iOS - Not able to access Static method of swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to access **Swift code in Objective-c**.

I have written one class in swift which contains static method. I want to access that Static Method in objective C Class.

Here is Class declaration:

```
@objc class LocalizedResource: NSObject {

    /*!
    * @discussion This function will get localize string for key

    * @param key Localize key
    * @return String for locaized key
    * @code LocalizedResource.getStringForKey(key);
    */
    static func getStringForKey(key:String) -> String    {
        let frameworkBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let value = frameworkBundle.localizedStringForKey(key, value: nil, table: nil)
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have made following settings for it:

1. Product Module Name : MyProject
2. Defines Module : YES
3. Embedded Content Contains Swift : YES
4. Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : YES
5. Objective-C Bridging Header : $(SRCROOT)/MySources/SwiftBridgingHeader.h

Also I have added **@Obj** before my class declaration in Swift class.

I have import MyProject-Swift.h in the .m file where I want to access that method.

But when I am trying to access it, it is not allowing me to access that static method.

Is any one having solution for it? Is there something missing?

Thnaks.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the class and of the static method.

Comment: you might be adding static method. Please add class func..

Comment: I have edited the question with Class Declaration I have made in Swift file

Comment: That should work. How do you call it in Objective-C, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: @MartinR
I am calling this method as follows:

`errorMessage.text =  LocalizedResource.getStringForKey(@"TIMED_OUT_ERROR");`

and it is giving me this error:

`Property 'getStringForKey' not found on object of type 'LocalizedResource'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your comment:

> I am calling this method as follows:
>
> ```
> errorMessage.text = LocalizedResource.getStringForKey(@"TIMED_OUT_ERROR");
> ```

In Objective-C, the "dot syntax" is used for properties,
not for methods. The correct call should be

```
errorMessage.text = [LocalizedResource getStringForKey:@"TIMED_OUT_ERROR"];
```

Comment: `errorMessage.text = [LocalizedResource getStringForKey:@"TIMED_OUT_ERROR"];`

This is correct Line.
Thanks once again

Answer (score 37):

Note in Swift 4 and the build setting `swift 3 @objc inference` is `default`, we must explicitly mark function as `@objc`, or it will not generate class function in Swift bridge header.

Comment: This answer is that i want (:

Comment: You saved my time, Thanks. ;-)